# Python How to write the output of regex matches to a new text file?

Tags: python, regex

I have an input text I'm scanning for matches.

I then create a new text file based on a user given name.

Then I run 2 regex scans on the input text, and only the matches are copied to the new text file.

Thats how it should go but nothing happens. No error, nothing. The output text file gets created, but it is empty.

Regexes:

```
phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''(

(\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))? # area code

(\s|-|\.)? # separator

(\d{3}) # first 3 digits

(\s|-|\.) # separator

(\d{4}) # last 4 digits

(\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))? # extension

)''', re.VERBOSE)

emailRegex = re.compile(r'''(

[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+ # username

@ # @ symbol

[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+ # domain name

(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}) # dot-something

)''', re.VERBOSE)
```

Broken code to identify matches and paste to separate text file:

```
matches = []

for groups in phoneRegex.findall('input.txt'):

phone = groups[0]

outputFile.write(str(phone))

outputFile.write('\n')



for groups in emailRegex.findall('input.txt'):

email = groups[0]

outputFile.write(str(email))

outputFile.write('\n')
```

https://pastebin.com/3pTy2K8P

Comment: `for groups in phoneRegex.findall('input.txt'):` You're comparing the regex to the literal string `"input.txt"`. The regex engine is not taking that string, finding a file with that name, and matching the pattern against the text within that file, which is what it looks like you're expecting it to do.  Change that line to `for groups in phoneRegex.findall(open("input.txt").read()):`

Answer (score 0):

Like one of the commentors stated

```
for groups in emailRegex.findall('input.txt'):
```

does not look for matches in the input.txt file, but in the string "input.txt".

You need to read in the file as a string first (maybe do some post-processing if necessary) and save it to a variable, which you can then pass as the argument here.